# How to apply ODE45 solver correctly

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration, chaos

What is the relationship between number of datapoints and the time step and integration step? How to determine the step size so that I can generate `N` number of points?

For example, when `N=1000` datapoints (length of each of the time series) what should be `t` and the integration time step, `dt`. Again, if I want to generate `N=10k` then how to determine `t` and `dt`. The code below is for simulating the [Rossler system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6ssler_attractor). I am getting a funny plot instead of the usual attractor. I want to generate a user defined `N` number of points. But I cannot understand what values should `t` and `dt` should be taken. Rossler system should give a neat chaotic attractor at the parameter values of `a=0.38,b=0.2,c=5.7`.

```
a = 0.38; b = 0.2; c = 5.7;
t = [0,50];
xinit = [-20 0 0];
ross = @(t, x) [-x(2)-x(3); x(1) + a*x(2); b + x(3)*(x(1) - c)];
[T, X] = ode45(ross, t, xinit);
figure; hold on;
plot3(X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, when N=1000 datapoints (length of each of the time series) what should be t and the integration time step, dt

`t` should be your 1-by-N 'datapoints'. With `ode45`, it allows you to do initial and end points only.

`dt` is the durations between neighbouring time points. You don't need it for `ode45`. If you need to know what Matlab does, check [this article](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/ode_suite.pdf) or pick up the first book in their [reference list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html).

> how to determine `t`

It should come from the nature of your problem.

You can start with uniform timestep. For example, `t=`[`linspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html)`(0,50,10000)`.

I did a quick Google search on adaptive timesteps and the first few links seem rather good. Starting with an [educational writing](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/55903/18-034Spring-2007/NR/rdonlyres/Mathematics/18-034Spring-2007/Projects/euler.pdf) illustrating the concept using Euler's method.

`ode45` uses adaptive timesteps of its own choosing. Their method is described in the first linked article.

> The code below is for simulating the Rossler system.

Your `odefun` format is right. Ofc, since we communicate only in [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), your coefficients must be right -- though that is something you may wish to double-check.

I do not have an opinion on whether the results below would be a correct solution. (I would not wish to.)

You can experiment with different tolerance values to see if a more sensible result can be produced.

Perhaps you will find it helpful to know that I have seen strange and incorrect results from `ode45` from very simple systems when my manually implemented non-adaptive RK45 and even Euler method worked as expected.

If I were you, I would simultaneously engage in a conversation at math.stackexchange on why and when adaptive ODE methods converge. Perhaps that will give you insight as to why and when `ode45` results may be highly inaccurate.

> I want to generate a user defined N number of points.

`ode45` will decide its own timesteps. Inputting an expanded `t` as opposed to just the end points tells `ode45` to use the number of points you desire. It is also useful for telling `ode45` to integrate backwards in time. Format for generating an 1-by-N vector is `t=`[`linspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html)`(t0,tf,N)`. You do not need and cannot customize `dt` for `ode45`.

---

Using `ode45`, 100k points, your constants:
[image: 1]

Using `ode113`, 100k points, `a=0.2`, and `ode15s` result looks similar:
[image]